# Plotting random points inside parabola using Python?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, math, graph

Was wondering how to generate 100 random points inside the parabola below and also ensure that these points have y values smaller than 15000?

```
x = np.linspace(-100,100)
y = 2*x**2+10*x

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

[image: plot]

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: use `random`, use `if`, use `for`, use `while`? [ask]

Comment: What have you tried? Also you surely mean that the `x` values must be limited to about +/-80

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

The usual boilerplate

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

We want to generate points in a rectangle (x0, x0+dx) × (y0, y0+dy), and discard points under the parabola.

The y range is <strike>easy, `y0=0` and `dy=15000`</strike>
`y0=ymin=y(-2.5)`, `dy=15000-ymin`, for the x range we need to solve  2 x² + 10 x = 15000 ⇒ x₁ = (-5 - √(5²+2·15000))/2 and x₂ = (-5 + √(5²+2·15000))/2.

```
x0, dx = (-5-np.sqrt(30025))/2, np.sqrt(30025)
y0, dy = 2*6.25+10*(-2.5), 15000.0-(2*6.25+10*(-2.5))
```

Now we generate a list of random points, that is initially void

```
xy = []
```

Then, we generate the coordinates of a point, check if it's valid and repeat until we have accumulated 100 valid points.

```
while len(xy) < 100:
    x = x0 + np.random.rand()*dx
    y = np.random.rand()*15000
    if y<2*x*x+10*x : continue # i.e., start a new iteration w/o appending
    xy.append((x,y))
```

Now, the plotting, I'll use a range that is symmetrical wrt the axis of symmetry of the parabola, then I plot the points using `scatter` (note the `*zip(*iterable)` that is used to transpose a 2D list) and finally I draw a horizontal dashed line.

```
x = np.linspace(-2.5-100, -2.5+100, 801)
y = 2*x*(x+5)

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.scatter(*zip(*xy), s=1)
plt.hlines(15000, x[0]-5, x[-1]+5, linestyles='dashed')

plt.show()
```